# getline returning empty string

Tags: c++, fstream, getline, string

I'm having problems with the getline instruction from fstream.
this is a snippet from my code:

```
boolean_1=true;
while(true)
{
   if(boolean_1)
   {
      //some stuff
   }
   else
   {
        save_file.open("save.txt", fstream::in);
        //some stuff
        save_file.close();
   }

    mission_file.open(filename, fstream::in);
    mission_file.getline(buffer_line, 256);

    //some other stuff

    boolean_1=false;
    save_file.open("save.txt", fstream::out);
    //write something
    save_file.close();    
}
```

This code should open the mission_file the first time it runs, and open a save file at the next iteration. The save file is created at the end of every cycle.
At least it should work like this.
Because, the first time everything works flawlessly, but in the next iteration, "mission_file.getline(buffer_line, 256);" returns an empty line, making the program crash.
Also, if boolean_1 starts as false, the cycle works fine until the next one.

I have already checked the existence of the required ".txt"s, both mission_file and save_file return is_open() true.

Comment: You don't appear to be checking the whether `getline` succeeds, presumably you want to stop after you reach the last line?

Comment: 'getline' fails only when i've already loaded a mission_file, done all the stuff with it and then reopen it at the beginning of the next cycle. It doesn't fail when i open it for the first time, and i omitted from this snippet the code to stop before the EOF.

Comment: It would help a lot if your code sample was complete and compilable (albeit minimal). Right now we can see that you have a variable called `mission_file` but you don't show where or how it is declared or all of the pertinent operations that you perform on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's impossible to see from the code extracts that you've posted but it sounds like you are re-using the same `std::fstream` object for each cycle.

It would be clearer to create a new local object inside the loop at the point at which you need to re-open the file.

If you must re-use the same `fstream` object to open a new file (or the same file another time) you must make sure to clear any stream error flags before reading from the new file.

Performing a `clear` at some point before the first read from the new file should do this.

```
mission_file.clear()
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you making sure that `mission_file` is being closed, because I don't see `mission_file.close()`. Or is it that you just missed to put that line in the code snippet here.

Comment: Sorry, i forgot to put the mission_file.close() in the snippet, anyway it's in the code.